# How I can command the four switches without microcontroller

Tags: digital-logic, switches, flipflop, switching

I try to command 2 SWitch H bridge rectifier (two mosfet two diode)  during the positive half cycle M1 switching and M2 be considered as a secondary switch that is continuously ON. During the negative input voltage half-cycle, the roles of the converter legs are swapped
So now I will try to command 4 MOSFET any person have an idea about the  new Command signal without microcontroller implementation

[image]

the two signal Pwm1 and Pwm2[image]

I find in the internet this solution but the author used microcontroller .How I modified my circuit to obtain the same  signals  commands ?
I can used S-R flip-flop?

[image]

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/116327/discussion-on-question-by-cheniour-oussama-how-i-can-command-the-four-switches-w).

Comment: They make Half bridge drivers. You apply a signal there are two outputs. One is non inverted and the other is inverted. Some also have features to setup the dead time.